# Specific Android Studio project won't open

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm able to open all my AndroidStudio projects but one. The window don't even show up and the preview form Windows is just a blank page.

I already try to clean cache, delete gradle files - from the project and the one located on the user directory - .

[preview with a working project on the side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGsn5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be some corrupted project configuration file.
Try to create a new project, check that everything works, and then copy the `app/src` folder from the old one to the new one (**only** the `src` folder).
You didn't mention it but I hope you have already tried restarting your pc, otherwise try.

Comment: Not the solution I was expecting tbh. But sure, it should work. The equivalent from reboot everything.

Answer (score 1):

I was resolving this issue for weeks and this is what finaly helped:

1. open "File/Open Recent/Manage Projects..."
2. find the faulty project and remove it from recent projects
3. open "File/Open..." and open the project again manually
4. when the dialog appeared, I pressed "this window" and it finally opened.